# IIS/Azure multi domains all retun the same certificate

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, ssl

We have a Web Role running on Azure, the Service is running multi Domains on the service. Each Domain has its own certificate defined in the IIS supporting HTTPS connections.

It all worked correctly for months but yesterday it all broke, the IIS started serving the same certificate for all our domains. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out if you bind by mistake a certificate to the machine ip and not to a host.